# Mensaje de error al insertar un tweet en html

Tags: html, agregación

Compañeros, me aparece este error por cada tweet que deseo agregar a la pagina que estoy creando:

```
 Line 217, Column 18: "async" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute
      <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">…
✉
Error Line 217, Column 79: required attribute "type" not specified
…t async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
✉
The attribute given above is required for an element that you've used, but you have omitted it. For instance, in most HTML and XHTML document types the "type" attribute is required on the "script" element and the "alt" attribute is required for the "img" element.

Typical values for type are type="text/css" for <style> and type="text/javascript" for <script>.
```

¿Cómo lo puedo corregir? Estoy copiando literal el código fuente del tweet.

Comment: Hola Andres! Bienvenido a la comunidad de Stack Overflow, acabo de intentar insertar un tweet en mi pagina web de pruebas y me ocurrió el mismo error, creo que este error viene del codigo de Twitter ya que la vista previa tampoco funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez tu problema se deba a un bloqueo de las peticiones asíncronas, el navegador las bloquea en local, intenta correr tu web en apache (con XAMPP por ejemplo).